# Print statement gives "cannot find symbol" message

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm playing around with java and came across the following problem.

I have the following classes

```
class Training{

    public static void main(String[]args){

       book firstBook = new book("Hamlet","William Shakespeare");
       book secondBook = new book("Heart of Darkness", "Joseph Conrad");
       book thirdBook = new book("Database Design","M Hernandez");

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Total number of books is " + book.noOfBooks + "\n");

       System.out.println();
    }
}

public class book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private int id;
    public static int noOfBooks = 0;

    public book(String n, String a){
        name = n;
        author = a;
        id = ++noOfBooks;

        System.out.printf("The book you've just created is %s\n", this);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s by %s id %d", name, author, id);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }
}
public class whatDay {

    System.out.println();
}
```

NetBeans throws a message 'cannot find symbol' for the print statement in the `whatDay` class.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `System.out.println();` because you did not put it into a method.

Try to put the System.out.println() into a method.
For example:

```
public class WhatDay {
    // Constructor
    public WhatDay() {
        System.out.println()
    }
}
```

By the way: You should start class names with capital letters.

Have fun with Java :)

Answer (score 1):

the error is coming because your call to println in the whatDay class is not enclosed in a method.